# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I make AJAX calls to the same domain as the origin. For example the origin is `http://foo.com/folder/index.php` and the domain in my AJAX call is going to `http://foo.com/folder/finder.php`. So my AJAX call looks basicly like this :

```
var url = "http://foo.com/folder/finder.php?";
request = createRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = confirmCall;
request.send(null);
```

In this case `finder.php` gives me a directory list back. `request` is a global var. The AJAX call itself works perfect.

While having no problem with CORS issues with different browsers on my computer other people getting the typical CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` forbidden error. Strange in this sense is that they get this error not always.

Please note : I red most of the relevant links to CORS, such as MDM for instance. They all refer to cross domain calls as this is the issue.

But I defenetly not making calls to cross domains. Or do I oversee something? Please, can anyone help me on this issue having the same problem ?

Comment: Do you have  `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  ` at the top of the PHP file? @Ben

Comment: I'm not sure if would be an isse are requests from http to https or the other way round, or if some users use www.foo.com and it tries to request from foo.com. It might be worth taking a look at though.

Comment: Have you tried using a relative link instead of a full url? eg. var url = "finder.php";

Comment: What is `createRequest()`?  Are you 100% sure that people with a problem aren't showing `http://www.foo.com` in their browser which would create a cross origin request when requesting from `http://foo.com`?

Comment: @Varun - No i don't, is that mandatory ?

Comment: @Chrisoffer Karlsson - Well, if I do not get things wrong, all clients around the globe will make calls only to the domain where the site is originated from. So there should not be any CORS related issues actually. Strange though.

Comment: @som - No, is that possible ? I'll give it a try

Comment: @jfriend00 - Sorry , I did not get your point. Could you make an example ?

Comment: @Ben Try with the header in the PHP,should work then.

Comment: If your web server responds to `http://www.foo.com/index.php` and an occasional user goes to that page, but your ajax request goes to `http://foo.com/index.php`, that would be an accidental cross origin request and would be denied if your server wasn't enabled for CORS.

Comment: @Varun - This is concrete proposal, thanks. But is it not then becoming a "hacker" issue ? The door is wide open for everybody. Or ?

Comment: @jfriend00 - This is a good point. Actually my AJAX request has no "www" in the url. So how to deal with this ? Is this a server configuration issue ?

Comment: Use a relative URL for the ajax request and you should not have a problem.  Leave off the domain and just use `/folder/finder.php?`.  It will then use whichever domain is in the page.

Comment: If your site respond to www.foo.com and foo.com with the same content. You should redirect one to the other. For example, you should redirect http://foo.com to http://www.foo.com. This redirection can be done by server configuration. BTW, its a god practices for SEO too.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I'll try that and comme back to you.

Comment: @Yoann - Your proposal (recomendation) has to be realized through provider admins, I guess. Unfortunatelly I am not. But I will follow your point and coming back.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Genius … it works … even on Sunday ;-) If this is standard practice , does there exist an official article to this issue ? It may help other people reading about CORS not to step in the same trap.  All other guys : thanks for your quick response. I got the solution now (I hope).

Comment: @som - I give you a vote up also, because you finally made the same proposal : "use relative URL's". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seems to have fixed the problem, I'll write an answer to cover it so you can finish this question.

If your server accepts both `http://www.foo.com/folder/index.php` and `http://foo.com/folder/index.php` (which is not uncommon), then you have to be very careful about how you request your Ajax calls because if someone types `http://www.foo.com/folder/index.php` into the browser bar so that's the URL used for the web page, but then your Ajax requests goes to `http://foo.com/folder/finder.php`, then the browser will complain that `http://foo.com` is not the same origin as `http://www.foo.com` and will refuse to make the Ajax call for cross origin security reasons.

There are a couple of ways to fix this.  First off, you can fix it server-side by auto-redirecting `http://foo.com` to `http://www.foo.com` so all Ajax requests come from `http://www.foo.com` and then use that domain in your Ajax URLs.

Or, on the client side, you can make all your URLs be domain relative so they automatically use whichever domain the web page is using.  So, instead of requesting your Ajax URL as `http://foo.com/folder/finder.php?`, you would use `/folder/finder.php?`.  The browser will automatically use the same domain the web page is loaded from and thus no cross-origin issue.

Comment: I accepted your answer, still I am curious. Would it not be best practice to use only "relative paths" in Ajax calls when you make calls to the same domain ?  Or are there any other traps involved with "relative paths" ?

Comment: @Ben - yes, it is best practice to use paths without the domain for requests intended to go to the same domain as the page.  It solves problems with https also.  It is also best practice to tune your server so you don't have multiple domains serving the same page (auto-forward one to the other) because this helps with SEO and prevents this cross-domain problem too.